# Resource for Born-Oppenheimer approximation

Tags: resource-recommendations, atomic-physics, molecular-dynamics, born-oppenheimer-approximation

I'm studying molecular physics but I'm failing in finding a good book with an accurate description of the Born-Oppenheimer approximation. I've tried some resource on the Internet and the McQuarrie's book but I'd prefer something more precise. Do you know any good book or article?